# Can't add multiple bucket policies to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

im unable to add domain level privacy bucket policy with zencoder bucket policy. they work when i add one at a time but when i try to implement both it doesnt work. im just looking for a solution to implement both bucket polices in one bucket. i tried to add condition from the domain level privacy to zencoders bucket policy. but the domain level privacy stops working.
here is the bucket policies im trying to add .

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::newbbbb/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "https://www.vlogmo.com/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "ZencoderBucketPolicy",
"Statement": [
  {
      "Sid": "Stmt1295042087538",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
          "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::395540211253:root"
      },
      "Action": [
      "s3:GetObjectAcl",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:PutObjectAcl",
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET/*"
  },
  {
      "Sid": "Stmt1295042087538",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
          "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::395540211253:root"
      },
      "Action": [
      "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
      "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET"
  }
]
}
```

Comment: "it doesnt work" - what does it mean? What exactly is happening? Any errors? And how are you adding those policies?

Comment: @Marcin im just looking for a solution to implement both bucket polices in one bucket. i tried to add condition from the domain level privacy to zencoders bucket policy. but the domain level privacy stops working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> im just looking for a solution to implement both bucket polices in one bucket

You can't do this. A bucket can have **only one policy**. So you have to join your two policies, into one by adding new `Statement`:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "ZencoderBucketPolicy",
"Statement": [
  {
      "Sid": "Stmt1295042087538",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
          "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::395540211253:root"
      },
      "Action": [
      "s3:GetObjectAcl",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:PutObjectAcl",
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET/*"
  },
  {
      "Sid": "Stmt1295042087538",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
          "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::395540211253:root"
      },
      "Action": [
      "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
      "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET"
  },
  {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::newbbbb/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "https://www.vlogmo.com/*"
                }
            }
        }
]
}
```

Comment: im getting Write access to 's3+us-west-1://zencoder123/hls-low/hls-low.m3u8' was denied. If this is a S3 URL, you may need to grant read access to Zencoder and try again. Get more information in the documentation. the domain level privacy is working though

Comment: @tonyMacias I would suggest making new question, as this is new error, with details how exactly are you accessing the bucket? Any commands that you use? Any other IAM policies that your IAM user/role has.